# Pandas dataframe loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` and I'm looking for the min value in it.

```
print(df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin()])
```

It's working and i can print the whole 'line', This is the result:

```
Country              Switzerland
City                      Zurich
Airport                   Zurich
Carrier         Vueling Airlines
Type                      Direct
Date         2017-09-05T00:00:00
Price                      12360
AirportId                    ZRH
Name: 97, dtype: object

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I print for example only the `AirportId` column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By filtering against it:

```
print(df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin()]['Airport'])
```

If you intend to write data into that cell, keep using `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin(),'Airport']
```

Comment: technically chained indexing, `print(df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin(),'Airport'])` would be better IMO +1 nevertheless

Comment: You are awesome! :) Thank you!

Comment: @EdChum faire enough to get more explicit variation for R/W case. edited, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

let's say this is your data frame:

```
your_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Airport':['x','y','z'], 'type': ['A','B','C'],
      'price':[5450, 5450, 15998]})
```

you can access th efirst column like this:

```
print your_df.loc[your_df['price'].idxmin()].values[0]
```